# Find words in lists using python by entering part of them

Tags: python, list, find

Given the list:

```
my_list = ['barrow', 'yellow', 'green', 'red', 'mellow']
```

I'd like to find the words inside that list that would match '****ow' ('*' is any letter). This should return 'barrow', 'yellow' and 'mellow' (words included in thet list, formed by six letters whose two last letters are 'ow')

Comment: I'll post an answer in a sec, but just as a side note, you should avoid using `list` as a variable name because it's a type in Python already

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service; what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I know. I've been researching and I don't know how to face it.

Comment: So what exactly have you "researched"?! Which of the various ways of parsing text with Python have you so far dismissed as somehow inappropriate? Did you think of searching for e.g. "python match word", which would have taken you [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to approach your problem  is to use [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html), provided your hay stack is a list of string. In case if its not, you may have to do a pre-convertion to a string

```
>>> import fnmatch
>>> my_list = [2345, 3245, 2343, 8746]
>>> fnmatch.filter(map(str, my_list), "2*4*")
['2345', '2343']
>>> my_list = ['barrow', 'yellow', 'green', 'red', 'mellow']
>>> fnmatch.filter(map(str, my_list), "*ow")
['barrow', 'yellow', 'mellow']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> new_list = [w for w in my_list if (len(w) == 6 and w[-2:] == 'ow')]
>>> new_list
['barrow', 'yellow', 'mellow']
```

Answer (score 0):

`[x for x in my_list if x.endswith('ow') and len(x) == 6]`

This uses a list comprehension that takes all elements of `my_list` that end with 'ow' and have length 6, which is exactly what you want. For a more general solution, you would build a regex `re` that matches the strings you want, and use `re.match()` as the condition

Comment: This works for the example I've posted. Will it also work in this case?: my_list = [2345, 3245, 2343, 8746]. I want to find the number in my_list that are [2*4*] (2345, 2343)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> my_list = ['barrow', 'yellow', 'green', 'red', 'mellow']
>>> [e for e in my_list if re.search(r'....ow', e)]
['barrow', 'yellow', 'mellow']
>>> [e for e in my_list if re.search(r'2\d4\d', str(e))]
[2345, 2343]
```